# Arduino output problems

Tags: arduino

I am currently attempting to make a calculator, and this is the first part of the equation where the user will enter a number using an IR remote.

Currently my problem is when I am outputting the numbers I have entered into the array as strings (so I can combine them later on) it outputs odd characters.

This is my code so far:

```cpp
#include <boarddefs.h>
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <IRremoteInt.h>
#include <ir_Lego_PF_BitStreamEncoder.h>


int RECV_PIN = 6;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

int part1digits = 0;
String part1[16];
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
  if (part1digits <= 15) {
    while (!irrecv.decode(&results)) {
      /* DO NOTHING WHEN NO IR SIGNAL IS RECEIVED
        This WHILE loop will run continuously, doing nothing
        until there IS a signal received
      */
    }
    // if IR signals is received, then do this
    getCode();

    part1digits++;
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
      Serial.print(part1[part1digits]);
    }
    // The while loop below is to 'stop' the program
while(1){}

  }
}

void getCode() {
  if (results.value == 16738455) {
    part1[part1digits] = "0";
    Serial.println(part1[part1digits]);
  }
  else if (results.value == 16724175) {
    part1[part1digits] = "1";
    Serial.println(part1[part1digits]);
  }
  else if (results.value == 16718055) {
    part1[part1digits] = "2";
    Serial.println(part1[part1digits]);
  }
  else if (results.value == 16743045) {
    part1[part1digits] = "3";
    Serial.println(part1[part1digits]);
  }
  else if (results.value == 16716015) {
    part1[part1digits] = "4";
    Serial.println(part1[part1digits]);
  }
  else if (results.value == 16726215) {
    part1[part1digits] = "5";
    Serial.println(part1[part1digits]);
  }
  else if (results.value == 16734885) {
  part1[part1digits] = "6";
  Serial.println(part1[part1digits]);
  }
  else if (results.value == 16728765) {
    part1[part1digits] = "7";
    Serial.println(part1[part1digits]);
  }
  else if (results.value == 16730805) {
    part1[part1digits] = "8";
    Serial.println(part1[part1digits]);
  }
  else if (results.value == 16732845) {
    part1[part1digits] = "9";
    Serial.println(part1[part1digits]);
  }

  //    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
  delay(250); // Delay, so you don't send 3 signals back to back
  // while the button is depressed.
  irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
}
```

A small snippet of output I am getting after I have entered in all my values are:

```
ôïÿ9ÝKÏÞóõx;ÿo×§ÿ^Øè«ÙÝ™ë]^ �ßå¿n'Þ
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you selected the wrong baud rate on the serial monitor. The code says 9600, so make sure that the serial monitor is selected at that baud rate.

Answer (score 0):

Check your baudrate again, try to change baudrate between 9600, 38400 or 57600